# Gauss-Manin and Hilbert modular forms

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, reference-request

There is a geometric formulation of Hilbert modular forms (HMFs) that parallels that for classical modular forms (sections of a line bundle over the moduli space of Hilbert-Blumenthal Abelian varieties). However, it doesn't give the automorphic forms on $G = \text{Res}_{\mathcal{O}_F/\mathbb{Z}}\text{GL}_2$, but rather on the subgroup $G^*$, where $G^*(R) = \{g \in \text{GL}_2(\mathcal{O}_F\otimes_\mathbb{Z}R) \mid \text{det}(g) \in R^\times \subset (\mathcal{O}_F \otimes_\mathbb{Z}R)^\times \}$. By restricting automorphic forms to this subgroup, we may view the space of HMFs for $G$ as a subspace (which is in fact a summand) of the space of HMFs for $G^*$, and there is an explicit projector $\mathfrak{e} \colon$ {HMFs for $G^*$} $\to$ {HMFs for $G$} given by averaging over some group action.

There's also a Gauss-Manin connection $\nabla$ that sends the nearly algebraic HMFs of weight $k$ and type $r$ for $G^*$ to the space of nearly algebraic HMFs of weight $k+2$ and type $r+1$ for $G^*$. Viewing an HMF for $G$ as an HMF for $G^*$, we can apply $\nabla$ to it, but a priori it won't yield an HMF for $G$ (i.e., an element of that subspace).

I'm looking for a reference on how this projector $\mathfrak{e}$ and the connection $\nabla$ interact. I've tried to argue that they commute, but I think anything in this direction would require knowing what $\nabla$ looks like. (Honestly, I'd love an early reference involving $\mathfrak{e}$ at all. I can't find one easily.)

Comment: I imagine the discrepancy here is solely the matter of missing some connected components and the inclusion of $G$-HMFs into $G^{*}$-HMFS and the projector $\mathfrak{e}$ are extending sections to other components respecting group action on $\pi_{0}$ and restricting section to certain components. In this way everything is geometric ($H_{dR}^{1}$, $\nabla$, etc.) so I could only imagine $\nabla$ and $\mathfrak{e}$ commute.

Comment: I don't think that's the entire story based on e.g. how $G^* \subset G$ looks $p$-adically for various $p$. But I've only seen $\mathfrak{e}$ in a recent paper (which doesn't mention $\nabla$), and it's not in some of the older references I've looked through.

Comment: Actually, if we add the special linear group into the story, it feels like that is what's going on, at least kind of. Can we use the "sections of a bundle on a moduli space" interpretation of modular forms (and HMFs) when we really mean automorphic forms on SL$_2$, not GL$_2$?

Comment: I don't think p-adic or any arithmetic consideration really matters here because after all everything a priori is complex algebraic ("classical automorphic forms are adelic automorphic forms"). I can certainly believe that $\mathfrak{e}$ or the inclusion does not interact obviously with rational structures.

Comment: What is the main reference you are looking for $\mathfrak{e}$?

Comment: My main reference is about $p$-adic properties, it's "On overconvergent Hilbert modular cusp forms" by Andreatta, Iovita, and Pilloni. The projector is discussed in the introduction and in section 4.1. It's available here: http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/vincent.pilloni/AIP2.pdf

Comment: There is really nothing scary happening here. The map $\nabla$ will preserve the image of $G$-forms inside $G^*$-forms; this is completely obvious if you write down the $q$-expansions (both $\nabla$, and the condition for being in the image of $G$, are completely explicit in terms of Fourier coefficients). The only real subtlety to keep track of is that the naive restriction map from $G$-forms to $G^*$-forms is not injective in general (so one has to bulk up the target of the map by summing over spaces of $G^*$ forms for several different levels); this is what is done in AIP.